# Reporting not-witnessed events

Tags: word-usage

In English, is there a modal, like 'can' or 'would', or a short expression that adds the following meaning to a sentence: "I did not see it with my own eyes but I was told about it"? There is one in Turkish: '**mish**'. For example, Bob goes to New York, Alice tells me about it and Mike asks me Bob's whereabouts and I answer him by saying "He **mish** went to New York". This sentence tries to tell Mike that "I have not witnessed Bob going to New York, but someone else, Alice, told me about it, so I am not sure if what I am reporting is true". "Mish" is commonly used in Turkish for reporting not-witnessed events.

Comment: One way we do this in English is by saying, "I heard..." "I heard (from Alice) he went to New York."

Comment: *Reportedly, supposedly, said to be, heard, the talk is that, a little bird tells me, the grapevine is that, rumor has it that,* ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [evidentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidentiality) when it is grammaticalised in other languages, but English doesn't have these grammatical markers. For your example, why not say

> I heard he went to New York.

Answer (score 3):

You could try "reportedly".  If you have doubts about the truthfulness of the information you heard, you could say "supposedly" or even "allegedly" (which is used in legal-speak to refer to an accused person in regard to a crime committed.) But "reportedly" seems the closest to what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Try also *apparently,* or a parenthetical *"so it is said" / "so they say":*

> - "He apparently went to New York"
> - "He went to New York, so it is said".
> - "He went to New York, so they say".